# How to form an equation based off $x$ and $f(x)$ values

Tags: problem-solving

So I'm making a program (and I know, this isn't stack overflow) but I need help on ONE algorithm in order to finish it for good. Here's the pattern I'm dealing with:

When $x = 8,  f(x) = 1$

When $x = 10,  f(x) = 4$

When $x = 13,  f(x) = 8$

This is hard to explain, but I need to figure out the pattern that $f(x)$ is going based off the 3 given $x$ values.

Would I be able to find an equation based off this information? Or is it too little information provided?

Comment: Without any further information, we cannot deduce what $f(x)$ equals for other values of $x$. What is the context of this?

Comment: There are any number of possible answers, here is one:$$f(x)=\lfloor\tfrac x8\rfloor+3\lfloor\tfrac x{10}\rfloor+4\lfloor\tfrac x{13}\rfloor\ .$$

Comment: If you can provide more data points, I could work (at least, I could try).

Comment: You do realise that there are infinitely many functions that fulfill these conditions, right?

Comment: ... for example, the polynomial
$$
f(x) = -\frac{1}{30}x^2 + \frac{21}{10}x - \frac{41}{3}
$$
It looks ugly, but goes exactly through those points.

Comment: Also, an arc of a circle $f(x)=-\tfrac{81}2+\tfrac12\sqrt{-4x^2+588x+2441}$.

Comment: I should probably add: this is for a program, so preferably the SIMPLEST equation would work. And no, sorry. These are all the data points I'm given. Is it impossible?

Comment: Then it is obviously $f(x) = \begin{cases}1, x=8\\4, x=10\\8,x=13 \end{cases}$